# How can I hightlight the correct menu when a subpage is selected

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

There is my website structure

Main menu

```
Home [/] / Products[/products] / Contact Us [/contact-us]
```

Products submenu

```
Product1 [/products/product1]
Product2 [/products/product2]
```

When I'm on product1 or product2 page, I want the product menu to be highlighted.

Does anyone have a simple idea about how I could do that without javascript?

---

Problem resolved!

Thanks to Piotr, I realized that my approach to fix the problem was wrong and that I simply had to work toward making native navigation work.

I had a problem with the navigation query links since my website was multilingual but I just had to add a localization part to query link content items to fix the problem and have working native submenus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the default navigation, all items on the selection path (from current one up to the root) should have a CSS class **'current'** applied. Just apply some CSS styling to this class and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

there is a module for this in gallery also. 
http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.dsendelb.Navigation